# What functions have $f (t + 1)=f (t)+ 2$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

The functions have to be linear. Do I have to find the functions that satisfy the condition or is there a specific name for functions that satisfy these conditions. This question is the $26$th question in Strang's calculus at section $1.1$, If it is to find functions that satisfy these conditions, how do I do it?

Thinking without any math procedures, I find that if you take $f(t) = 2t$, then $f(t+1)$ will be $2t+2$ which will be same as $f(t) + 2 = 2t + 2$.

Are there any more functions that will satisfy these? Is there any procedure to find these or we can find this only through trial and error?

Comment: Ummm... $f(t) = 2 t$, perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f$ is specified as linear, let $f(t)=at+b$. Then
$$a(t+1)+b=at+b+2$$
$$at+a+b=at+b+2$$
$$a=2$$
and $b$ is unrestricted. Thus the possible functions $f$ are $f(t)=2t+b$ where $b\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following works:

Here is another way:

$f(1)-f(0)=2$   $+$

$f(2)-f(1)=2$    $+$

$\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot$

$f(n)-f(n-1)=2$
$\implies f(n)-f(0) = 2n \implies f(n)=2n+f(0)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $n$ is extended to $\mathbb{Z}$ using a similar argument where one starts at $f(0)-f(-1)=2$ and so on.

Since $f$ is assumed to be linear we must connect each $[x,x+1]$ interval from endpoint to endpoint with a line (which can be done in one unique way), and this extends the domain of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How did you get $f(n) - f(0) = 2n$ ? Did you take n as 1 so 2n would remain as 2? So you are assuming f(0) as constant, wouldn't constant change for different values of n. It would be $f(1)$ if n is taken as 2. It cannot be $f(0)$ always right?

Comment: Adding those equations gives a telescoping sum where the only terms left are the first and last terms (It may help to write out a few terms to see why all the middle terms cancel, but it should be clear). The $RHS$ for each equation is $2$ and there are $n$ equations resulting in $2n$. This is a function not a relation so $f(0)$ has a single output which is our constant term.